# Calling Procedure is not Working as it is in the For Loop in Node.js

Tags: node.js

The calling procedure in the loop is not working. By default it is a synchronous process.

Please help me understand what is wrong with my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

  manageMerchantAccountInput['records'][0]['id'] = results[i].id;

  procedureArray.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) =>

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

      connection.query('CALL `mobiezyb2c`.`manageMerchantAccount_prc`( ?, @p_out_mssg_flg, @p_out_mssg)', [JSON.stringify(manageMerchantAccountInput)],
        function(error, results, fields) {
          connection.release();

          if (error) console.log(error);
          else

            resolve(results[0][0]);
        });
    })
  ))
}`
```

Comment: Grammar and formating.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using async executions (e.g. Promises) and you must execute them in a sequential order - there are plenty of working examples online on how to do so.

One of those examples I showed in my Gist where I utilize reduce() function in order to execute promises sequentially on the array of arguments. Here is this simplified example:

https://gist.github.com/anvk/5602ec398e4fdc521e2bf9940fd90f84

Maybe try this for your problem?